# OpenShift: rhc setup receives error 403

Tags: openshift

When first setting up the rhc setup for our openshift enterprise installation, I get the following error:

```
Connect without checking the certificate? (yes|no): yes
DEBUG: Connecting to https://master.sb.local:8443/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG: Created new httpclient
DEBUG: Request GET https://master.sb.local:8443/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: SSL Verification failed -- Using self signed cert
DEBUG:    code 403  284 ms
You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Any ideas how to solve this? I'm pretty sure it's just a small glitch I'm missing.

Comment: On Linux you can probably place the cert in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates

Comment: you probably want to add the command you're trying to run as well as the openshift version to get help faster